# How to show recent projects at right click for PyCharm?

Tags: ide, windows-10, pycharm, jetbrains-ide

I'm using JetBrains PyCharm 2018.2.1.

I've added the app icon to the taskbar (Windows 10, at the bottom of screen). Everytime I click it, it starts and open the last project. But sometimes I want to open a recent project. I don't want to open the last project first and then switch to a recent project I want to open.

I notice that someone with MacOS can right click the icon and it will show recent projects list to be chosen. How can I achieve that?

The taskbar:

[image: toolbar]

What I want (take MS Visio for example, when I click the icon with right button it shows recent opened files):

[image: example]

Comment: You may also tell IDE not to automatically open last project ... so you will see the  Welcome screen where you will have to choose what project to work with. Check `Settings/Preferences | Appearance & Behavior | System Settings | Startup/Shutdown | Reopen last project on startup` -- should be there in PyCharm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please vote for [IDEA-75238](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-75238) in order to move it up in the queue and receive notifications regarding the progress of the issue. See more information on working with tracker at https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241135-How-to-follow-YouTrack-issues-and-receive-notifications .

As for now, http://jetbrains.com/toolbox/app provides similar functionality for managing projects and even various IDE versions and other products. It even handles automatic updates without any need to click anywhere or go to websites and download anything.